# Std::async with variadic templated function error

Tags: c++, templates, asynchronous, static

Here is the code i'm trying to run:

```
class Logger {
public:
    template <typename... T>
    static void log(T&&... args) {
        std::async(std::launch::async, &Logger::_logStart<T...>, std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }

private:
    template <typename... T>
    static void _logStart(T&&... args) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_logLock);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
1>c:\c++\pv264_project\src\Logger.hpp(14): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::future<result_of<_Ty>::type> std::async(std::launch,_Fty &&,_ArgTypes &&...)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=decay<_Ty>::type (decay<_ArgTypes>::type...)
1>        ]
1>c:\c++\pv264_project\src\Logger.hpp(14): note: With the following template arguments:
1>c:\c++\pv264_project\src\Logger.hpp(14): note: '_Fty=void (__cdecl *)(const char (&)[10],std::string &&,const char (&)[9])'
1>c:\c++\pv264_project\src\Logger.hpp(14): note: '_ArgTypes={const char (&)[10], std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>, const char (&)[9]}'
```

I've read this ([C++ async with variadic template can not find correct function template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104064/c-async-with-variadic-template-can-not-find-correct-function-template-speciali)), and I've added the template to passing of _logStart, but still the template specialization is failing. Where is the problem here?

**Edit:** After further investigation the problem seems to be with calling this log function with char literal. It seem to be deduced differently for the function type and when it is forwarded as an argument. How can I guarantee that all the types in _logStart and std::forward(args)... will get deduced to the same type even with const char*?

Comment: Off topic: std::async will return you a std::future, you might want to check the behavior of its destructor!

Comment: I don't need to return anything from that async call and also I am using std::launch::async so it gets called immediately

Comment: I've updated the code and everything seems to compile: https://godbolt.org/g/t7QSxM

Comment: FYI: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future > See (since C++14)

Comment: You might use `std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){Logger::_logStart(std::forward<T>(args)...);});`.

Comment: @Jarod42 That is a nice suggestion to use lambda, but the problem with it is that it takes all the parameters by reference so it won't be efficient with rvalue references. Also std::forward in this case won't do anything because everything would be lvalue.

Comment: `std::forward` works, even in that case, as I use `T` from "outter" function.